# Kubernetes pod restart using Kubernetes Client for C#

Tags: c#, kubernetes

Is there a way to have something equivalent of : `kubectl rollout restart deployment my-deployment`
in Kubernetes Client for C#?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for any `kubectl` command you can run `kubectl --v=9` to see the contents of each API request and response.

In this case you can see the PATCH body being sent is:

```
{
  "spec":{
    "template":{
      "metadata":{
        "annotations":{
          "kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt":"2020-08-27T12:26:00+10:00"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then kubernetes controllers work out the rest.

Some `kubectl` commands are more client heavy and will have some logic that would need to be reimplemented. In this case, just a simple check to see if the [deployment has been "paused"](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/3874cf79897cfe1e070e592391792658c44b78d4/pkg/polymorphichelpers/objectrestarter.go#L32-L37)

I'm not a c# person, but from the [patch example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/master/examples/patch/Program.cs) it's something like

```
var dply = client.ReadNamespacedDeployment("foo", "default");
var restart = new Dictionary<string, string>(dply.Metadata.Annotations) { ["kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s") };
var patch = new JsonPatchDocument<V1Pod>();
patch.Replace(e => e.Metadata.Annotations, restart);
client.PatchNamespacedDeployment(new V1Patch(patch), "foo", "default");
```

Comment: Tried the above code with minor modifications. The code ran fine, but somehow my deployment was not restarted. In my actual scenario, I am trying to restart the Istio-Ingressgateway deployment in Istio-System namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can try *`patch`*. Emulate this behavior:

```sh
$ kubectl patch deployment mydeployment -p \
  "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

Looks like patch [is supported by the C# client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/master/examples/patch/Program.cs).

✌️

Comment: this also did not work for me and gave an error of Unprocessable Entity : "kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Pod \"details-v1-78db589446-l26w5\" is invalid: [metadata.labels: Invalid value: \"{\\\"version\\\":\\\"ed4e6e8ed4ffa03fe7d5b9d2c27cc8c478625ade64be2859cae3da0db9e5ee2e\\\",\\\"initContainers\\\":[\\\"istio-init\\\"],\\\"containers\\\":[\\\"istio-proxy\\\"],\\\"volumes\\\":[\\\"istio-envoy\\\",\\\"istio-data\\\",\\\"istio-podinfo\\\",\\\"istio-token\\\",\\\"istiod-ca-cert\\\"],\\\"imagePullSecrets\\\":null}\": must be no more than 63 cha

Comment: My cluster has istio sidecars running on each pod

Comment: I just provided an example, I realized it was for the Pod. So what you want to do is patch the deployment. Looks like the other answer has the deployment patch, if it doesn't work you can check the events/logs.